# Can a git project track a directory listed in my global gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working on a project that needs to track it's `node_modules` directory. I don't really want to remove my global gitignore reference to that directory because all other projects should *not* be tracking the `node_modules` directory.

Is there a way to force git to track something at the project level? Or do I need to go through all projects verifying each has it's own ignore and then remove the reference from me global gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a negation to a local `.gitignore` to make git track it only for this project.

```
!node_modules
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If a file is tracked, its presence in an ignore file is ignored (if I may put it this way :-) ).

I've always said that `.gitignore` is kind of the wrong name for the file, because it's not really a "list of files to ignore".  Instead, it has two purposes.  Git checks for an ignore-file entry in two cases:

- when it's about to gripe that there's an untracked file, or
- when it's about to clobber a file and it's not sure if this is allowed.

The first case is most often seen from `git status`: adding a file, or pattern, to your ignore files tells git "please shut up about `*.o` and the like, they're not supposed to be tracked, so don't complain that they're not tracked."  In this case the entries should probably be in a file called `.git-shut-up-about-these-files`.

The second case is a bit more insidious.  Let's say you have, in a git repository, a commit with files `a1` and `a2`, and that's your *current* commit (because it's the tip of the branch, or because you did `git checkout <commit>`, or whatever, and those two files are in that commit: for argument sake let's say that this is the tip commit on `master`).  Let's also say that you have *another* commit `1234567` with just file `a1`, no `a2`.  If you now do:

```
git checkout 1234567
```

git must *remove* file `a2`.  That's OK, because it's in your other commit (the tip of `master`), `a2` is in there.  If you switch back:

```
git checkout master
```

git re-creates `a2`.

But what if, in the tip of `master`, there's a file named `important` that's *not* in `1234567`?  You `git checkout 1234567` and then you stop and make some important notes:

```
$EDITOR important
```

You write out those important notes and exit the editor, and then decide to `git checkout master`.  Git now needs to clobber the notes you just wrote, because the tip of `master` contains a file named `important`.

What git will do in this case is check your ignore files for the name `important`.  If that's in there, git feels free to wipe out that file and replace it with the one from the commit.  If *not*, `git checkout` warns that checking out would overwrite `important` and asks you to get it out of the way first.

These file name entries should probably be in a file called `.git-go-ahead-and-clobber-these-files-they-are-unimportant`.

Note that there is no entry you can make to mark a file "not to be stored in the repostory, but precious: do not clobber".

Comment: Really informative answer. I appreciate the clarity. Always feels much better to learn the thinking behind a command rather than just the command itself. Thanks!